# how to implement ranking metrics of Pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I am new to PySpark. I'm trying to implement **ALS** (Alternating Least Squares matrix factorization) for a recommendation purpose using *python* and *pyspark.mllib.recommendation* pakage . According to the [PySpark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#ranking-systems) I've found that I should use the *ranking* *metrics* to evaluate the system on implicit feedbacks . but unfortunately the documents is not update at python part and when I've tried to implement it on my own I've got some different issues on RDD types . please help me to find the bug. I'm not sure wether I should use *.rdd* at *createDataFrame* or maybe I should use another function to make the rdd type ...

```py
def build_model_Als(self):
   data = self.load_from_redis()
   self.dataframe = Pandas.DataFrame({"user": data[0:, 0], "item": data[0:, 1], "rate": data[0:, 2]})

    train = self.dataframe.sample(frac=0.8 , random_state=99)
    test = self.dataframe.loc[~self.dataframe.index.isin(train.index), :]

    ts = test.drop(columns=['rate'])
    ps = test.drop(columns=['user'])

    ratings = spark.createDataFrame(self.dataframe).rdd
    testdata = spark.createDataFrame(ts).rdd

    self.model = ALS.train(ratings, rank=10, iterations=10, lambda_=0.01, nonnegative=True)
    predictions = self.model.predictAll(testdata)
    ratesAndPreds = ratings.join(predictions)
    metrics = RankingMetrics(ratesAndPreds)
    print("Mean average precision =", metrics.meanAveragePrecision )
```

and here is the error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o207.meanAveragePrecision.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 213.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 213.0 (TID 273, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getSeq(Row.scala:283)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getSeq(rows.scala:166)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI$$anonfun$newRankingMetrics$1.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1070)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI$$anonfun$newRankingMetrics$1.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1070)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter.merge(StatCounter.scala:55)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter.(StatCounter.scala:37)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter$.apply(StatCounter.scala:158)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$stats$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:43)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions$$anonfun$stats$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DoubleRDDFunctions.scala:43)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score -1):

I've tried different ways based on RDD and Dataframe of PYSpark to build, fit and evaluate the model. Finally I've found that the *"join"* function can't help to implement *ratesAndPreds* , because it should be built in RDD structure with *spark.SparkContext.parallelize* function . I've changed the function as below:

```
 def build_model_Als(self):
    data = self.load_from_redis()
    self.dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"user": data[0:, 0], "item": data[0:, 1], "rate": data[0:, 2]})
    train = self.dataframe.sample(frac=0.8 , random_state=99)
    test = self.dataframe.loc[~self.dataframe.index.isin(train.index), :]
    ts = test.drop(columns=['rate'])
    logging.info("start train")

    als = ALS(rank=10, maxIter=10, regParam=0.01, userCol="user", itemCol="item", implicitPrefs=True,
              ratingCol="rate", coldStartStrategy="drop", nonnegative=True)
    self.model = als.fit(spark.createDataFrame(train))
    logging.info("done")

    global_user = None
    user_list = np.array([], dtype=np.float64)
    testItems = list()
    for row in test.iterrows():

        if row[1]['user'] != global_user:
            user_list = np.append(user_list, row[1]['user'])
            testItems.append(int(row[1]['item']))
            global_user = row[1]['user']
        else:
            testItems.append(int(row[1]['item']))
        true_list[global_user] = testItems

    pandasDf = pd.DataFrame({'user': user_list})
    sub_user = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDf)
    labelsList = list()
    for user, items in self.model.recommendForUserSubset(sub_user, 30).collect():

        predict_items = [i.item for i in items]
        labelsList.append((predict_items, true_list[user]))
    labels = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(labelsList)
    metrics = RankingMetrics(labels)
    print(metrics.meanAveragePrecision)
```

> The point is *spark.sparkContext.parallelize* return a right RDD to find intersection at *RankingMetrics.meanAveragePrecision* , but *join* can't.
>   for instance : spark.sparkContext.parallelize([([1,2,3,4], [1,2,12,13,1]), ]) 
>   makes a proper RDD for meanAveragePrecision and the result is : 40%